# totally vs extremely vs absolutely

Tags: word-choice, word-difference

> 1. He is *absolutely* tall for his age-almost two meters already
> 2. He is  *extremely* tall for his ages-almost two meters already.
> 3. He is *totally* tall for his ages-almost two meters already.

I want to know *absolutely* and *totally* can use for describing the size.My dictionary did not describe in which condition they should use.
Which is suitable most, totally or absolutely or extremely? What are the differences between these adverbs?

Comment: What does your dictionary tell you about these adverbs? Is there something specific that you don't understand about the definitions you have found in your research?

Comment: I want to know *absolutely* and  *totally* can use for size.My dictionary did not tell in which condition they should use.

Answer (score 4):

*Tall* is a qualitative adjective describing the quality of a person —  here the height of a teenager.

This type of adjective is capable of being 1) graded (for quality, rank, size, etc.) by the use of adverbs most common of which are *fairly, very, really* and *extremely;* 2) compared: *tall-taller-the tallest*.

The adverbs *absolutely* and *totally*, meaning "to a complete degree", don't allow any grading or comparison, so from the three sentences, only the second one should be marked as "correct" in a multiple choice assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Extremely is similar to very. Absolutely and totally both mean completely. He can be very tall but he can't be completely tall so use extremely in this context. Try substituting words for synonyms for this type of question.